# How to show error message when there is no result result?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a note taking app. I would like to show the error message only if there is no search result. The problem is that currently I'm displaying the error message even when I don't have any notes in the array, which is not what I want. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code and what I've tried so far:

```
  const [notesList, setNotesList] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = React.useState<string>("");

  const addNote = (): void => {
    setNotesList([...notesList, ""]);
  };

  const deleteNote = React.useCallback(
    (idx: number): void => {
      const newList = [...notesList];
      newList.splice(idx, 1);
      setNotesList(newList);
    },
    [notesList]
  );

  const updateNote = React.useCallback(
    (idx: number, text: string): void => {
      const newList = [...notesList];
      newList.splice(idx, 1, text);
      setNotesList(newList);
    },
    [notesList]
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const storage_string = sessionStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);
    if (!storage_string) return;

    try {
      const savedNotes = JSON.parse(storage_string) as string[];
      if (savedNotes) setNotesList(savedNotes);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    sessionStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(notesList));
  }, [notesList]);


  const getFilteredNotes = (notes: string[], query: string) => {
    if (!query) {
      return notes;
    }
    return notes.filter((note) => note.includes(query));
  };

  const filteredNotes = getFilteredNotes(notesList, query);
  const updateQuery = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
    setQuery(event.target.value);
  const handleSearch = debounce(updateQuery, 500);

  return (
    <div ref={wrapperRef}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <SidePanel showSidePanel={showSidePanel}>
        <HeaderContainer>
        <SearchInput placeholder='Search notes' type='text' onChange={handleSearch} />
        <Button variant='icon' onClick={addNote}>
          <AddIcon/>
        </Button>
        </HeaderContainer>
        {filteredNotes && filteredNotes.length > 0 ? filteredNotes.map((note: string, idx: number) => (
          <Note
            onChange={updateNote}
            remove={deleteNote}
            idx={idx}
            text={note}
            key={idx}
          />
        )) : <Text>No results found</Text>}
      </SidePanel>
        <ToggleButton variant='primary' onClick={toggleSidePanel}>
          <NoteIcon width='2rem' height='2rem'/>
          Notes
        </ToggleButton>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: check if `notesList` isn't empty as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition will only ever render notes, or your fallback text:

```js
        {filteredNotes && filteredNotes.length > 0 ? filteredNotes.map((note: string, idx: number) => (
          <Note
            onChange={updateNote}
            remove={deleteNote}
            idx={idx}
            text={note}
            key={idx}
          />
        )) : <Text>No results found</Text>}
```

As [@kelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244921/kelly) mentioned above, you need to check your notesList and if you don't want to show your fallback text then skip rendering this section.

There's many ways you can do that - abstracting the logic for what to render given different scenarios to a function would be more readable, but you can try this to see if it solves your problem:

```js
      {notesList.length > 0 && // <- this is new, and the rest is wrapped in parenthesis ()
        (filteredNotes && filteredNotes.length > 0 ? (
          filteredNotes.map((note: string, idx: number) => (
            <Note
              onChange={updateNote}
              remove={deleteNote}
              idx={idx}
              text={note}
              key={idx}
            />
          ))
        ) : (
          <Text>No results found</Text>
        ))}
```

If your notesList is empty, it won't render anything